# SQL Server : reasons not to use default database settings for ANSI_NULLS?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I've been given a case where a customer is experiencing this error - once in a while:

> *Msg 8624, Level 16, State 21, Line 1
>
>   Internal Query Processor Error:
>   The query processor could not produce a query plan. For more
>   information, contact Customer Support Services.*

They're using our software, and running it on SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) and at compatibilty level 100 (SQL Server 2008). The database however was originally created on a 2000 or 2005 machine (can't reproduce anymore) and then moved to 2008 R2 recently.

The stored procedure in question has an ugly looking `INSERT` statement which grabs data from ten (yes!) "copies" of a given table, all joined with `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` against one another (same table - ten JOINs against it).

The one solution I found that seems most appropriate has to do with various settings - it's recommended to use:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set ANSI_PADDING ON
set ANSI_WARNINGS ON
set CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
set ARITHABORT ON

set NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
```

OK - sure - I can set these before every stored procedure I create (or alter).

My question to the database gurus out there would be: any risk when I set these as default settings for my database?

E.g.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET ANSI_NULLS ON
```

and be done with it? Thoughts? Insights? Recommendations?

Comment: No, not at all.  In fact, the ability to turn `ANSI_NULLS` off has a limited life.  Soon enough that won't even be an option, it'll always be on.  The only time I've ever seen any form of reasoning for setting `ANSI_NULLS` off, is because there's developers that can't fathom the true meaning of `NULL`, and therefore want to use typical conditional logic with it.  Again, terrible reason and I look forward to the permanent on for `ANSI_NULLS`.

Comment: You like troubleshooting weird performance issues? http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: @gbn: well, not really - the query processor **cannot** come up with a plan - nothing to performance-troubleshoot there! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a risk at all.  In fact, the ability to turn `ANSI_NULLS` *OFF* has a limited lifespan. Soon enough that won't even be an option, it'll always be *ON*. The only time I've ever seen any form of reasoning for setting `ANSI_NULLS` *OFF*, is because there are developers that can't fathom the true meaning of `NULL`, and therefore want to use typical conditional logic with it. Again, terrible reasoning and not justifiable.  I look forward to the permanent *ON* setting for `ANSI_NULLS`.

Comment: Eight years and four version later, nothing has changed. I really wouldn't hold my breath on Microsoft ever deprecating anything.