# Find out what setting were used for a given stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

As a [follow-up to my previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22365/sql-server-reasons-not-to-use-default-database-settings-for-ansi-nulls):

is there a way to need to find out what the `ANSI_NULLS` and `ANSI_PADDING` etc. settings where when a given procedure was created in my database ?

It seems my customer there has several stored procedures and a few triggers that have been "tweaked" - but unfortunately, using a "wrong" set of those database settings. Can I find out *which* procs and triggers are affected, or do I need to re-create all of them with the proper settings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be determined from `sys.sql_modules`:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo1 AS SELECT 1;
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo2 AS SELECT 1;
GO

SELECT name = OBJECT_NAME([object_id]), uses_ansi_nulls
  FROM sys.sql_modules
  WHERE OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) IN (N'foo1', N'foo2');

GO
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.foo1, dbo.foo2;
```

Results:

```
name   uses_ansi_nulls
----   ---------------
foo1   1
foo2   0
```

Some other useful columns:

```
object_id
definition
uses_ansi_nulls
uses_quoted_identifier
is_schema_bound
uses_database_collation
is_recompiled
null_on_null_input
execute_as_principal_id
```

Note that some settings (e.g. `arithabort`, `ansi_warnings`, `ansi_padding`) are not stored with the object. Also you will need to recompile the procedures with the correct settings for any that have been identified as "wrong."

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot, Aaron! Too bad it only shows two (`ansi_nulls` and `quoted_identifier`) - but better than nothing!

Comment: [Stored procedures execute with the SET settings specified at execute time except for SET ANSI_NULLS and SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER. Stored procedures specifying SET ANSI_NULLS or SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER use the setting specified at stored procedure creation time.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx)

Comment: Huh, didn't know you could drop multiple procedures like that in one statement. Nice!

Comment: @Jon works for several DML commands, I usually use it for DROP TABLE not DROP PROCEDURE.

Comment: I know that the question is very old, but just a FYI: both uses_ansi_nulls and uses_quoted_identifier are not reliable. I just verified in a database that makes heavy use of ANSI_NULLS = OFF and it doesn't report all stored procedures decorated with that option.

Answer (score 0):

In relation to the [ANSI_PADDING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx) portion of your question, you can use `sys.columns`

From [ANSI_PADDING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx) MSDN article:

> Controls the way the column stores values shorter than the defined
>   size of the column, and the way the column stores values that have
>   trailing blanks in **char, varchar, binary, and varbinary** data. 
>   ...
>   **This setting affects only the definition of new columns**. After the
>   column is created, SQL Server stores the values based on the setting
>   when the column was created. Existing columns are not affected by a
>   later change to this setting.

Here is a query to check the ANSI Padding value for object columns of the affected data types:

```
SELECT TableName = QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) 
                + '.' 
                + QUOTENAME(t.name)
    , ColName = c.name
    , ColTypeName = ty.name
    , c.is_ansi_padded
    , ObjectType = t.[type]
    , ObjectTypeDesc = t.type_desc
FROM sys.columns c 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects t on t.object_id = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.types ty 
        ON ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id 
        AND ty.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
WHERE ty.name in ('char','varchar','binary','varbinary')
    --AND c.is_ansi_padded = 0 --you can filter on 0 to show the columns that are not following best practices.
ORDER BY 1,2
;
```